# Not able to select an option in drop-down javascript-protractor-jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

In the below code it is printing out the option text but not clicking on the element.

```
element.all(by.xpath(xpath_of_an_option_in_dropdown)).each(function(item)
{
    item.getText().then(function(value)
  {
      logger.log('info','----------'+value);
      item.click();
  });

});
```

Other drop-downs in the same webpage are working fine except this one drop-down.
Also note that the above xpath is written so that it will return only one option of drop-down.

HTML code:

```
<div style="width: 300px" class="ng-star-inserted">
<select class="abc-inputBox ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
<option value="null">None selected</option>
<!---->
<option value="27: _GroupByServiceA" class="ng-star-inserted"> ServiceA  </option>
<option value="28: _GroupByServiceB" class="ng-star-inserted"> ServiceB  </option>
</select>
</div>
```

I have also used below code:

`element(by.cssContainingText('option','ServiceA')).click();` 
but it is not working. No error is given but bo action is performed.

Comment: Do you have to first click on the dropdown itself to open it up and show the options?

Comment: Show the dropdown HTML code. The logger print out, so the option should be clicked, but nothing response to the click, so you can't see anything happen from page.  Try sleep for a long time to debug this issue. Another reason is you should click on child/parent element of `item`, maybe the click event is bind to child/parent element of `item`, not bind on the `item`.

Comment: added HTML code. Other drop-downs are working fine on same page with cssContainingText().click(); method

Comment: I assume the "click" event listener is already attached.
Did you try to add a "detectChanges" method after ".click()"?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `each()` fires off actions at the same time against all elements. Try to iterate using elementArrayFinder.**get(arrayFinderIndex)**

Comment: I have also used below code:

element(by.cssContainingText('option','ServiceA')).click(); but it is not working. No error is given but bo action is performed.